# The site can't be reached

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I  tried to implement reverse proxy and workers. Its working fine except if i enter port number in url i saying ' The site can't be reached' .

```
192.168.50.15   Is working fine.

192.168.50.15:8069  it gives error ' This site can't be reached'
```

How can i resolve this?

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
#odoo server
upstream odoo {

server 127.0.0.1:8069;

}

upstream odoochat {

 server 127.0.0.1:8072;

}



# http -> https server {

listen 80;

server_name 127.0.0.1:8069;

rewrite ^ (. *) https: // $ host $ 1 permanent;

 }



server {

listen 443;

server_name 127.0.0.1:8069;
proxy_read_timeout 720s;

proxy_connect_timeout 720s;

proxy_send_timeout 720s;



# Add Headers for odoo proxy mode

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $ host;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $ proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $ scheme;

proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $ remote_addr;



# SSL parameters

ssl on;

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt;

ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/server.key;

ssl_session_timeout 30m;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

ssl_ciphers' ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256: ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384: ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384: DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM- SHA256: DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256: kEDH + AESGCM: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256: ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA: ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA: ECDHE- RSA-AES256-SHA384: ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA: ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA: DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256: DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA: DHE-DSS- AES128-SHA256: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256: DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA: AES128-GCM-SHA256: AES256-GCM-SHA384: AES128-SHA256: AES256-SHA256: AES128- SHA: AES256-SHA: AES: CAMELLIA: DES-CBC3-SHA :! ANULL :! ENULL :! EXPORT :! DES :! RC4 :! MD5 :! PSK :! AECDH :! EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:! EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA :! KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA ';

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;



# log

access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;

error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;



# Redirect requests to odoo backend server

location / {

  proxy_redirect off;

  proxy_pass http: // odoo;

}

location / longpolling {

    proxy_pass http: // odoochat;

}



# common gzip

gzip_types text / css text / less text / plain text / xml application / xml application / json application / javascript;

gzip on;

}
```

**odoo-server.conf**

```
[options]

; This is the password that allows database operations:

admin_passwd = admin

db_host = False

db_port = False

db_user = odoo

db_password = False

addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons

[options]

logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log

addons_path = / odoo / odoo-server / addons

xmlrpc_port = 8069

proxy_mode = True
workers = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution.

I replaced the IP address `127.0.0.1` with system's IP address like `192.168.2.211` in both config file.